# Compiling and running Java from the command line

Tags: java, compilation, runtime-error

I created the below project structure.

```
[~/Projects/CountWords]@Ubuntu1804  #> find .
.
./bin
./src
./src/main
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/App.java
```

This is App.java content :

```
package src.main.java;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hola");
    }
}
```

I compile my app as :

```
javac -d bin/ -cp src/main/java/ src/main/java/*
```

Which works fine. I am using an asterisk because I'll have more classes in that folder but I have only that one for now. This creates the following structure :

```
[~/Projects/CountWords]@Ubuntu1804  #> find .
.
./bin
./bin/src
./bin/src/main
./bin/src/main/java
./bin/src/main/java/App.class
./src
./src/main
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/App.java
```

But my problem is when I try to run the app. I assumed this would work :

```
java src.main.java.App
```

But this fails with :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.java.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.java.App
```

What am I doing wrong?

I know that it must be a very silly question, but I want to code a small/medium project by hand just to understand what the IDE does on its own. After working with Java for a while using Eclipse, I noticed I had no idea how to do this by hand and I want to change that.

Comment: Where do you run `java`? At project root or at bin/ ?

Comment: At the root level. Which is **/home/matias/Projects/CountWords**. If I try to do this : *java -cp bin/ src.main.java.App* I get this error :

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class src.main.java.App, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: @SantosshKumhar None of those commands worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define class path for java. 
There are two possibilites:

run

```
java -cp ./bin src.main.java.App
```

or change to bin directory and then run without cp

```
cd bin 
java src.main.java.App
```

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class src.main.java.App, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Do You still have the same code like posted above in your current App.java? Because I tried it out and it compiles and runs fine. I would suggest you remove everything else you have in your src/main/java and just leave App.java there and compile and execute again.

Comment: You are right! I rebooted and now it works! Thank you!